# How To Decrease Java GC Young Size Pause Time

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

I am trying to write Java program to understand gc optimization. I am newbie in java. The program read huge partitons key from cassandra concurrently, let's say 2 parallelism. After reading, i have nothing to do with the rows. They will be waiting GC. After reading 6 partition key, First GC runs and takes 10 seconds. In my opinion, first 4 partition key are being removed.

My problem is, 10 seconds gc pause two much, i use GC setting like below. Is there any suggestion?

```
java -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote \
  -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9010 \
  -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false \
  -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false \
  -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false \
  -Xms24g \
  -Xmx24g \
  -XX:+PrintGC \
  -XX:+UseG1GC \
  -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=200 \
  -XX:G1HeapRegionSize=6 \
  -XX:ParallelGCThreads=12 \
  -XX:ConcGCThreads=4 \
  -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions \
  -XX:G1NewSizePercent=70 \
  -XX:G1MaxNewSizePercent=80 \
  -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=30 \
  -jar mapreducer-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Comment: I'd consider GC tuning a bit too advanced for someone who's new to Java. Where did you get those GC settings?

Comment: Please show GC logs

Comment: Indeed, i have been dealing with gc for a long time. I set the properties while i am testing my program @Kayaman

Comment: *"I am newbie in java."* - *"i have been dealing with gc for a long time."* - Which of those seemingly contradictory statements is really true?   :-)

Comment: I am .net developer. I use open source java projects. I edited  GC settings for open source projects but not for program which i write :) @StephenC I think that if i edit gc settings for my program, i can have opinion for open source java projects :)

Answer (score 2):

In theory, the way to reduce GC pause times for young-space collections is to reduce the young / new space size.

In fact, these options:

```
  -XX:G1NewSizePercent=70 \
  -XX:G1MaxNewSizePercent=80 \
```

are forcing the young space to be between 70% and 80% of the total heap size.  That is probably why the GC is unable to meet the goal specified by this:

```
  -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=200 \
```

The young space need to be a lot smaller.

Comment: If i reduce those parameters, there would be frequent gc pause times. In my senario i am testing 10 huge arrays. It get those array in a loop with 2 paralellism. after i am done 2 arrays, i get next two arrays. any 2 arrays do not fit small young size area. I thought like if increase size of young size area and 2 array fit young area, gc would not move to older area and delete it immediately.

Comment: I suggest you just try tweaking the parameters and see what happens.  Note that reducing pause time is likely to increase the overall GC overheads.  If you want to minimize GC overheads, use the "throughput" compiler.

Comment: Yeah. My main purporse for this program to reduce the GC overheads. But do not know what do you mean "throughput" compiler. Could you explain it, please?

Comment: @user2599860 worst case pause time and number of pauses are two separate, somewhat conflicting goals. you should update your question to reflect what aspects you want to prioritize most (latency, throughput, memory footprint). And some of those options you picked are peculiar, you should outline what the motivation behind deviating from the defaults is, otherwise we have to guess or assume you were cargo-culting.